# Upload multiple videos one by one

Tags: php

Can anyone help me to upload multiple videos with a static name.I want to upload multiple videos one by one, which means if the user can upload any video of any type.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">      
  <input name="vv" type="file" id="file"/>
  <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" name="submit" id="upload"  style=" background:#03d5fb; color:#00264a; font-size:26px; margin-top:4%; width:23%;" />

 </form>

 <?php 
      $resultt=(mysql_query("Select * From aa where email  ='$_SESSION[login_user]'"));
      $rows= (mysql_fetch_array($resultt, MYSQL_ASSOC));
$id=$rows['id'];
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         if(!is_dir("images/videos".$id.'/')) {
                mkdir("images/videos".$id.'/'); 
                $filess = $_FILES['vv']['name'];
                $tmppath = $filess ['tmp_name'];
                $target_dir = "images/videos".$id.'/';
                $random=rand(0000, 9999);

                  move_uploaded_file($tmppath, $target_dir.'video'.$random.'.mp4');
                          echo "uploaded ";
           }
           else
           {
                 $filess = $_FILES['vv']['name'];
                 $tmppath = $filess ['tmp_name'];
                 $target_dir = "images/videos".$id.'/';
                 $random=rand(0000, 9999);

                 move_uploaded_file($tmppath, $target_dir.'video'.$random.'.mp4');
                      echo "uploaded ";
            }
    }
 ?>
```

This is sample code i am trying with no luck. Please give me some solution.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Try with `dropjone.js` it will helps you.

Comment: No this is not what i am looking for. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow user to select and upload multiple files, following are some simple tips for code

- Input name must be be defined as an array i.e. `name="inputName[]"`
- Input element must have `multiple="multiple"` or just `multiple`. To know
  more about this, check the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp)
- In your PHP file use the syntax
  `$_FILES['inputElemName']['param'][index]`

Now lets come to your code

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">      
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple"/>
    <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" name="submit" id="upload"  style=" background:#03d5fb; color:#00264a; font-size:26px; margin-top:4%; width:23%;" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php  
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        $result = mysql_query("Select * From aa where email = '".$_SESSION[login_user]."'");

        if($result)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $id = $row['id'];

            if(!is_dir("images/videos".$id.'/'))
            {
                mkdir("images/videos".$id.'/');
            }
            $target_dir = "images/videos".$id;

            // setup an array to check errors at the time of file upload
            $errors = array();

            //Loop through each file
            for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) 
            {
                // set the array of allowed extensions
                $allowed =  array('mp4', 'mkv');

                // extrach the file extension and check if it is valid
                $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                if(!in_array($ext,$allowed)) 
                {
                    $errors[] = "Invalid fiel extension.";
                }
                if(empty($errors))
                {
                    // make parts of file name to append timestamp to them to avoid uploading of files with same name
                    $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]);

                    $image_path = $path_parts['filename'].'_'.time().'.'.$path_parts['extension'];

                    //Setup our new file path
                    $newFilePath = $target_dir.'/'.$image_path;

                    //Upload the file into the temp dir
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i], $newFilePath)) 
                    {
                        //Handle other code here
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    print_r($errors);
                }
            }
            if(empty($errors))
            {
                echo "Success";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error while fetching records ".mysql_error();
        }
    } 
 ?>
```

Hope this helps to get your work done.